# Walking nested data by property

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, underscore.js

Let's say I have some data in an array. Each element of that array is an object that can have:

- an id
- some data
- a property (let's call it `sub`) that would contain an array of objects with the same properties (including that `sub` property).

Basically, that is a nested data where each object can hold more object.

I know I can walk that data tree with a recursive function like [this one](https://github.com/alexandernst/angular-multi-select/blob/9b21e04641d1f38e69a58217fabdf3cfeb5b30e2/src/angular-multi-select.js#L149), but I'm wondering if there is something that underscore or angular can offer me that would avoid me having to threat all that boilerplate and just do something like `data.findNestedById(12345, "sub");`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this https://github.com/s3u/JSONPath it might be helpful to you. Include the required script reference into your page and then you can try it somehting like this.

```
JSONPath({json: jsonObject, path: pathToLookFor});
```

Demo http://plnkr.co/edit/6uNp23JkuRkQCI1KnmAK?p=preview

Comment: This seems quite cool, but `http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/` doesn't seem enough explanatory. Do you know where could I get more docs/examples?

Comment: I think whatever is there on the readme page is enough to understand its usage.

Comment: Imho some more docs/examples won't hurt anybody. Anyways, after testing this for a few minutes I still think it's quite cool, but I'm not sure if that is what I'm looking for. After extracting the object I'm looking for, I need to modify it and put it back where it was. Can this lib do that?

Comment: I don't think so it will do that.